# Python functions double up printing

Tags: python, function

```
def cond(a,b):
    if (a>2 and 99+a<b):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def priiiiint(a,b):
    br=0
    for i in range(a,b+1):
        if(i%5==0 and i%7!=0):
            print('number {} dividable by 5 but not by 7! '.format(i))
            br+=1
    return(br)

def main():
    kraj=True
    while (kraj):
         a=int(input('nmbr AAAA: '))
         b=int(input('nmbr BBBB: '))
         if cond(a,b):
             priiiiint(a,b)
             kraj=False
         else:
             print('try again, b is not greater than a by 99 or more')
    br=priiiiint(a,b)
    print('there was total {} ...numbers'.format(br))
```

When i use numbers for example a=5 and b=105 it lists out the right results,but it does so twice...I have no idea why....Help apretiated :)

Comment: What is "the right results"? What is this program doing?

Comment: Its listing out all numbers which divided by 5 have 0 remnant...its a school assignemnt

Comment: you invoke `prnt` twice in you `main` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `prnt(a, b)` twice, thus printing the numbers twice.

Comment: How am I invoking it twice?  there is an "PRIIIIINT" function and "PRINT" command within it..?

Comment: It's invoked near the end and inside the while loop. Twice, printing inside it twice. Overall the keyword is *twice*

Comment: But that's only to give the value to br variable...But yea checked and it works when i remove the br ... but how am i going to check how many numbers were there then?

Comment: I don't really understand the *flow* of your program. But I did solve the problem you said with the double printing. <br> You don't have to print in that function, or just create a different function for just printing and another one for doing comparisons/math work.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `priiiiint(a,b)` two times, so it is printing everything two times. 
 
This is what you code should be to do what you like:

```
def main():
    kraj=True
    while (kraj):
         a=int(input('nmbr AAAA: '))
         b=int(input('nmbr BBBB: '))
         if cond(a,b):
             # Add br= here.
             br=priiiiint(a,b)
             kraj=False
         else:
             print('try again, b is not greater than a by 99 or more')
    # This line prints everthing another time: 
    #br=priiiiint(a,b)
    print('there was total {} ...numbers'.format(br))
```

Result:

```
nmbr AAAA: 5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
nmbr BBBB: 105                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
number 5 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                          
number 10 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                         
number 15 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                         
number 20 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                         
number 25 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                         
number 30 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                         
number 40 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                         
number 45 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                         
number 50 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                         
number 55 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                         
number 60 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                         
number 65 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                         
number 75 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                         
number 80 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                         
number 85 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                         
number 90 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                         
number 95 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                         
number 100 dividable by 5 but not by 7!                                                                                                                                                                                                        
there was total 18 ...numbers
```

To give you another advice on your code. 
 
You also can write it down like this:

```
def main():
    while True:
         a=int(input('nmbr AAAA: '))
         b=int(input('nmbr BBBB: '))
         if cond(a,b):
             # Add br= here.
             br=priiiiint(a,b)
             break
         else:
             print('try again, b is not greater than a by 99 or more')
    print('there was total {} ...numbers'.format(br))
```

If you have a loop that is `True`, it will always run, and exit that loop when it encounters a `break`. Yours is also good, but this is a more simple version that is used more because you need less code lines and your code will look cleaner.